# Pandas: How to replace Zero values in a column with the mean of that column, For all columns with Zero Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple values as zero. 
I want to replace the values that are zero with the mean values of that column Without repeating code.
I have columns called runtime, budget, and revenue that all have zero and i want to replace those Zero values with the mean of that column.

Ihave tried to do it one column at a time like this:

```
    print(df['budget'].mean())    
    -> 14624286.0643    
    df['budget'] = df['budget'].replace(0, 14624286.0643)
```

Is their a way to write a function to not have to write the code multiple time for each zero values for all columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So this is `pandas` dataframe I will using `mask` make all 0 to `np.nan` , then `fillna`

```
df=df.mask(df==0).fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: since i have multiple columns, 
will this replace the zero value with the mean of that respective column,
for instance 0 in budget column will be replaced with the mean of budget of column only 
and other columns that have 0 values will be replace with the mean of those columns?

Comment: I am sorry this is my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: @BobbyGee yes , it will :-)replace it the 0 with their means

Comment: Ty for you help. Is there a good resource that you recommend for me to learn pandas and python in more depth for data analysis.

Comment: @BobbyGee you can search pandas cookbook, I think that is good for start. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Same we can achieve directly using **replace** method.  Without **fillna**

```
df.replace(0,df.mean(axis=0),inplace=True)
```

Method info:
Replace values given in "to_replace" with "value".

Values of the DataFrame are replaced with other values dynamically.
This differs from updating with ***.loc or .iloc*** which require
you to specify a location to update with some value.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that this takes the 0-values into account as well? E.g. if a column has values 1,0,2, the 0 would be replaced by a 1 and not a 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

How about iterating through all columns and replacing them?

```
for col in df.columns:
    val = df[col].mean()
    df[col] = df[col].replace(0, val)
```

Comment: typically iteration is very slow compared to the vectorized array operations that pandas has builtin.